# Delete from a mysql table based on other 2 values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete from table `rk21a_virtuemart_product_categories` where `virtuemart_category_id` = 251 and `product_discount_id` from `rk21a_virtuemart_product_prices` = 0

Tried this query but doesn't work (deletes everything where `virtuemart_category_id` =251 not both conditions)

```
DELETE FROM rk21a_virtuemart_product_categories
   WHERE virtuemart_category_id = 251
   AND virtuemart_product_id IN (
   SELECT virtuemart_product_id
   FROM rk21a_virtuemart_product_prices
   WHERE product_discount_id = 0)
```

The tables are:

```
**rk21a_virtuemart_product_categories**
id   virtuemart_product_id  virtuemart_category_id
12   119                    160
13   121                    251
15   122                    173
20   123                    251
```

and

```
**rk21a_virtuemart_product_prices**
virtuemart_product_price_id virtuemart_product_id product_discount_id
1021                         119                  5
1022                         121                  0
1023                         122                  0
1024                         123                  10
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm a beginner..
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
DELETE c
FROM rk21a_virtuemart_product_categories AS c
INNER JOIN rk21a_virtuemart_product_prices AS p 
        ON c.virtuemart_product_id  = p.virtuemart_product_id
WHERE c.virtuemart_category_id = 251
  AND p.product_discount_id = 0;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8fd9/1)

In the first table `rk21a_virtuemart_product_categories` there are two rows with category id = 251, but in the second table there is only one row of them with `.product_discount_id = 0`, so only one row will be deleted.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much Abigail. Still deletes everything and i just notice, in rk21a_virtuemart_product_prices I can have multiple times the same virtuemart_product_id but with a different virtuemart_product_price_id and product_discount_id ...

Comment: @AlexandruFlorea - Can you please show me the rows of the table after the delete?

Comment: @AlexandruFlorea The results you expected from the delte